# HighMaps: Add second data series to tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have a second data series that I would like to add to the tooltip on this Highmaps chart. The variable with the second set of data (data2) is in place, but I haven't added the series yet as each time I do it breaks the code. I would like the tooltip to show the data from the first series and then beneath that, show the data from the second series. So it would read something like:

Value
State name: 4.50
Ranking: 3

I think the second series should be added like this:

```
{name:'Ranking: ',
data: data2
   }
```

but, like I said, when I add that it breaks the code. Beyond that, I can't figure out how to add that additional data to the tooltip, once I get there.

Here's the javascript code:

````
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.

var data2 = [
    ['mx-3622', 0],
    ['mx-bc', 1],
    ['mx-bs', 2],
    ['mx-so', 3],
    ['mx-cl', 4],
    ['mx-na', 5],
    ['mx-cm', 6],
    ['mx-qr', 7],
    ['mx-mx', 8],
    ['mx-mo', 9],
    ['mx-df', 10],
    ['mx-qt', 11],
    ['mx-tb', 12],
    ['mx-cs', 13],
    ['mx-nl', 14],
    ['mx-si', 15],
    ['mx-ch', 16],
    ['mx-ve', 17],
    ['mx-za', 18],
    ['mx-ag', 19],
    ['mx-ja', 20],
    ['mx-mi', 21],
    ['mx-oa', 22],
    ['mx-pu', 23],
    ['mx-gr', 24],
    ['mx-tl', 25],
    ['mx-tm', 26],
    ['mx-co', 27],
    ['mx-yu', 28],
    ['mx-dg', 29],
    ['mx-gj', 30],
    ['mx-sl', 31],
    ['mx-hg', 32]
];

var data = [
                    ['mx-3622', 0.00],
                    ['mx-bc', 5.59],
                    ['mx-bs', 4.05],
                    ['mx-so', 4.77],
                    ['mx-cl', 6.91],
                    ['mx-na', 8.88],
                    ['mx-cm', 8.01],
                    ['mx-qr', 4.87],
                    ['mx-mx', 5.01],
                    ['mx-mo', 0.089],
                    ['mx-df', 8.12],
                    ['mx-qt', 7.32],
                    ['mx-tb', 3.17],
                    ['mx-cs', 1.15],
                    ['mx-nl', 6.88],
                    ['mx-si', 6.64],
                    ['mx-ch', 2.19],
                    ['mx-ve', 0.66],
                    ['mx-za', 8.03],
                    ['mx-ag', 10],
                    ['mx-ja', 3.35],
                    ['mx-mi', 3.91],
                    ['mx-oa', 0.8],
                    ['mx-pu', 1.53],
                    ['mx-gr', 0.0],
                    ['mx-tl', 2.95],
                    ['mx-tm', 5.47],
                    ['mx-co', 9.46],
                    ['mx-yu', 8.62],
                    ['mx-dg', 4.47],
                    ['mx-gj', 8.33],
                    ['mx-sl', 4.35],
                    ['mx-hg', 4.75]
                ];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/mx/mx-all'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/mx/mx-all.js">Mexico</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Value',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
    }]
});```


Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sstoker/81w2revu/15/

Any help would be very much appreciated!!!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the second series in this way:

```
series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'Value',
    ...
}, {
    name: 'Ranking: ',
    data: data2
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/amtycfbL/

---

But I think that a better solution would be to add the additional data field to the first series data and display it in a tooltip by using `pointFormat` option:

```
data.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.push(data2[i][1])
});

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    ...

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Value {point.name} Ranking: {point.rank}'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['hc-key', 'value', 'rank'],
        data: data,
        ...
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j809rcva/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.keys

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. This is super close, but the number value of var data was lost.  It should look like this example.
Value
Baja California: 5:59
Ranking: 1

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Just a simple modification of pointFormat to:

pointFormat:'{point.name} {point.value} Ranking: {point.rank}'